# Can I make a functional component to be of a 'type' in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am constructing some Form components. I Created a `<Form />` `<Input />` and `<Button />` component. The input and button can be independently used, OR as a child of the `<Form />`.

The form can have any type of child, but I want to be able to look through the children from `<Form />` and see if a child is a valid `Form Element` but I'm not sure how to 'type' this.

I essentially would like to say that `Input` and `Button` are of type or valid `FormElement`, so that I may add some additional props through `React.cloneElement`

In the code below, I currently just do an `if` and chaining `||` for valid types that I am defining.

```js
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";

interface FormProps {
  children?: ReactNode;
}

const Form = ({ children }: FormProps) => {
  const cloneChildren = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (child) {
      const item = child as ReactElement;

      // I could later develop N amount of Form Elemnts. Ideally I'd like to just say
      // if item.type === FormElement instead of doing an || for each valid element
      if (item.type === Button || item.type == Input) {
        return React.cloneElement(item, { extraProp: "hello" });
      } else {
        return React.cloneElement(item);
      }
    }
  });

  return <form>{cloneChildren}</form>;
};

// This returns as 'input' type
const Input: React.FC = (props) => {
  return <input style={{ border: "3px solid red" }}></input>;
};

// this returns as 'button' type
const Button: React.FC = (props) => {
  return <button>{props.children}</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Form>
      <Input />
      <Button>Test Button</Button>
      <div>hi</div>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Comment: React components typically return the type `JSX.Element` regardless of their rendered contents, so there really isn't anything to type. A far as I know you can't enforce any particular structured content on the `children` prop with types.

Comment: I think you can only do this with class components since functional components don't have inheritance can implement interfaces.